# Build and run single file in a project with Microsoft Visual Studio 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a larger C# project which I made a class in and I would like to check my class and see if it does as I want it to do before I add it to the project. Is there a way to build and run that class on its own? I have made a suitable main for that class as well.

Comment: I use CSharp in Visual Studio.

Comment: this is called unit test

Answer (score 2):

Try making a proper [unit test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can run your code in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: I'm guessing that you can't run individual files in Visual Studio then? Thanks for the tips about the LINQPad though:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# compiler `csc` from command prompt

Comment: I'm guessing that you can't run individual files in Visual Studio then? Thanks for the tips about the csc compiler though:)

Comment: @plitter just use `csc filename.cs` to compile a single file